# Creating single Geoserver layer from two contiguous JPG+WorldImage files?

Tags: geoserver, jpg, world-file

I have two sets of files for two contiguous areas. I've been asked to merge these two areas into one and serve the resulting data set in Geoserver. What I have in each directory is what I reckon is a WorldImage data set generated with ArcGIS: I have a JPEG file, and others with the suffixes .jgw, .prj, .rrd, .aux, and .aux.xml.

I was able to convert each to a GeoTIFF, then merge the resulting GeoTIFFs with gdal_merge.py, with more quality loss than the boss likes, and I was told it should be possible to avoid going through merging and just tell Geoserver to create a layer covering both involved and contiguous areas.

I'm not sure that's possible, but I could be wrong. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ImageMosaic plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) for this purpose but you should be able to merge the two files and store them as GeoTiff with no loss of quality and get much better and faster results from GeoServer.

I would use something like:

```
gdal_merge.py -o out.tif -of GeoTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES file1.jpg file2.jpg
```

and I can never see the difference. If your boss is really fussy then use compress=deflate but since you are starting with a Jpeg it seems unlikely you will need this.

Then throw in some overviews to speed things up even more.

```
gdaladdo \
 --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG \
 --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR \
 --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL \
 -r average \
 out.tif \
 2 4 8 16
```

For all the gorey details see [Paul Ramsey's blog post](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html) and [GeoSolution's GeoServer on Steroids talk](http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gs-steroids-sgiannecfoss4g20130103?related=1).

Comment: Very clear, thanks! Bonus question: is it still worth it to create internal overviews given that we're going to create an ImagePyramid from the output file?

Comment: Depending on the size I wouldn't bother with an image pyramid if it's less than 2Gb (I think), Simonne's talk answers that in greater detail.